# Add Error Checking for New Form Submit: Vue+Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#crud-actions

I am using this table. There is no Error Checking if the form is empty. How will I add the Error checking?

I have tried with this:

```
<v-form @submit.prevent="save">

<v-text-field v-model="editedItem.customer_name" :rules="customerNameRules" required></v-text-field>


<v-btn color="blue darken-1" @click="save">Save</v-btn>
</v-form>
```

But it is not working!!! Just closing the Modal and added Empty Value in Array!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use @submit.prevent , then your `v-btn` needs a `type="submit"` to know it's a submit button. or if you want to use @click you can programmatically call validation with `this.$refs.form.validate()` like :

```
<template>
     <v-form ref="form">

          <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.customer_name" :rules="customerNameRules" 
          required></v-text-field>


          <v-btn color="blue darken-1" @click="save">Save</v-btn>
     </v-form>
</template>

<script>

   save() {
      if(this.$refs.form.validate()) {
         //save my item...
      }

   }
</script
```